# Trying to access an array with onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, addeventlistener

I am trying to apply an `onclick` function to an array of three elements, but setting the `onclick` property of the array does not work. Any ideas would be really helpful.
Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
var btnArray = [
document.getElementById('buttonOne'),
document.getElementById('buttonTwo'),
document.getElementById('buttonThree'),
];
console.log(btnArray); 
btnArray.onclick = function revilImg() {
console.log('hey');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't have an `onclick` property. You need to *iterate* over it first (I have chosen to use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), and attach the handler to each DOM element individually using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
var buttons = [
  'buttonOne',
  'buttonTwo',
  'buttonThree'
].map(document.getElementById, document)

console.log(buttons)

function revealImage () {
  console.log('hey')
}

buttons.forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', revealImage)
})
```

```html
<button id="buttonOne">#1</button>
<button id="buttonTwo">#2</button>
<button id="buttonThree">#3</button>
```

Comment: Where did you find, or knew, that when passing `document.getElementById` to the map function, it needs the `document` as _thisArg_?

Comment: @LGSon `document` is just an instance of `Document`, and it so happens that `getElementById` is defined on `Document.prototype` instead of as an own property of `document`. Try running `document.hasOwnProperty('getElementById')`, and you'll see it is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Add event listeners like this, where you loop through the array and add a handler to each object

```
var btnArray = [
  document.getElementById('buttonOne'),
  document.getElementById('buttonTwo'),
  document.getElementById('buttonThree'),
];

console.log(btnArray);

for (var i = 0; i < btnArray.length; i++){
  btnArray[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('hey');
  })
}
```

---

If your buttons share a common class, i.e. `mybuttons`, you can use `querySelecorAll()`

```
var btnArray = document.querySelectorAll('.mybuttons');

console.log(btnArray);

for (var i = 0; i < btnArray.length; i++){
  btnArray[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('hey');
  })
}
```